# how to add leaflet group layer control map to the flexdashboard data from userinput?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, flexdashboard

I am trying to built a dashboard with flexdashboard in r. I want to add leaflet group layer  control map in map window data from the user input.

[Here is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOZho.jpg)

**Here is my code**
Slider Input to show the filtered data

```
selectInput("mapcomp", "Select Map", choices = c("system size","connections"),elected = "system size")
    pal = colorFactor(palette = c("yellow", "brown", "red"), domain = df$company_name)
```

Filter data to change map and graph

```
 filteredData <- reactive({
      df[df$type == input$mapcomp,]
      })
```

Leaflet Map

```
    mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(data=df) %>%
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery")
      
      for(t in unique(filteredData$company_name)){ 
        sub <- filteredData[filteredData$company_name==t,]
    
    mymap <- mymap %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(
              data=sub,
              lng =  ~ lng,
              lat =  ~ lat,
              radius = 5,
              color =  ~pal(company_name),
              stroke = FALSE, 
              fillOpacity = 0.5,
              group = t
            ) 
          
      }
        
mymap %>% addLayersControl(
            overlayGroups = unique(df$company_name),
            options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
          ) 
        
      })
```

[**Dashboard output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFxw0.png)
How to add map layer(with group layer control) in map window?